# Django reset password return 127.0.0.1:800 instead domain name

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx

In my django project i implement forgot password link:

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

I have an nginx server configured like this (in location part):

```
 location /static/ {
            alias /var/www/web/core/frontend/static/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
            proxy_set_header  X-DTS-SCHEMA $subdomain;
            proxy_redirect http:// https://;
            }
```

i run my app using runserver with nohup (gunicorn and uWsgi does not work for my purposes)

```
nohup python manage.py runserver &
```

Now, when i call the reset password page (`/accounts/password_reset/`) and insert my email address, i get the email with link for reset password but the domain part of the link is `127.0.0.1:8000` instead the domain name.

How can i ask to django using currend domain instead `127.0.0.1:8000`?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: `select * from django_site` check domain field

Comment: Hi, i cannot find table django_site in my db

Comment: Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to your `location { ... }` block.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely current site's domain is incorrect. You can verify that by

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
get_current_site()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.shortcuts.get_current_site

Comment: Thanks, but how can i modify that  setting for using current domain?

Comment: You can either go to `/admin/` to the `Sites` section and modify or simply 

`site = get_current_site()
site.domain = 'your domain.com'
site.save()
`

Comment: Fantastic, but i have a wildchar domain *.mydomain.com, and the response link have to be different depending witch domain call reset password (eg test1.mydomain.com, test2.mydomain.com etc) can i set *.mydomain.com? thanks in advance

Comment: Please, read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/ It says that `get_current_site() function will try to get the current site by comparing the domain with the host name from the request.get_host() method.` So you can create multiple sites for that purpose. Make sure you don't specify `SITE_ID` in settings.py tho.